# Magento override login template only for my brazilian shop

Tags: magento-1.9, template, overrides

Can I override the login template only for my brazilian shop?
The template that I want to override is located here:

> app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml

Comment: If you are using same theme then you cannot override it. Are you using multiple store? What do you want to change in this login.phtml?

Comment: I have multiple stores. I want to remove the bulletpoints from an ul, but only for the Brasilian shop

Comment: Are you using rwd/default for other stores?

Comment: Hello @BorcheGlafche did you try my solution ?

Comment: @BorcheGlafche Can you update if any of the answers are working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can do:

```
if($store = Mage::app()->getStore()=='store_code'){ // you need to chnage store code
    your code for specific store;
}else{
    Default code for other store;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In two cases:

1. If you are using just this theme `rwd/default` brazilian shop as `store view` or `website`.
2. you can do it via xml properly like this :

**xml**

```
<customer_account_login>
    <reference name="customer_form_login">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template helper="your_module/getFormLoginTemplate" />
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

**Helper/Data.php**

```
public function getFormLoginTemplate()
{
    $storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
    $brazilianShop_code = 'br'; //for exemple
    switch($storeCode)
    {
        case $brazilianShop_code:
            return "persistent/customer/form/login2.phtml";
            break;
        default:
            return "persistent/customer/form/login.phtml";
            break;
    }

}
```

You create your custom form in : `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login2.phtml`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rwd/default theme for all websites then you need to create one folder like below:

> app/design/frontend/rwd/brasil/

and copy the below file:

> app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/rwd/brasil/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml

Then assign it in admin like below:

1. Goto System -> Configuration
2. Goto Design from left panel
3. Change the **Current Configuration Scope** to **Brasil store** and assign it
   like below:
   [image]

Do your customization to the below file for your brasilian store:

> app/design/frontend/rwd/brasil/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml

Flush the cache. And test.